# how to update / replace a file in a Django FileField()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a Django model that holds a file like so:

```
class Excel(models.Model):
    the_generated_file = models.FileField()
```

I know want to access this file with an updated version of the file.
If this was a int, foat or Json field etc I could use something like:

```
File_to_update = Excel.objects.all()
File_to_update.update(the_generated_file = my_new_excel_previously_defined)
```

But for some reason as it is of type `FiledField()` there is no update operation.
How can I replace the old file with a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you should try

```
file_to_update = Excel.objects.all()[0]
file_to_update.the_generated_file = 'foo'
file_to_update.save()
```